# Trap Ctrl-D in a Ruby Script with ARGF

Tags: ruby, command-line, argv

I am currently using ARGV.gets to capture user input from the command line. I want to allow Ctrl-D terminate the script, but don't know how to do this using Signal.trap or through error handling. I tried to find a list of trap codes for something like Ctrl-D but was unable to find anything I was looking for. Likewise, rescuing Exception doesn't work because Ctrl-D doesn't raise an exception. Is there a trap code for Ctrl-D or any other way to detect this?

**For example...
I am currently able to detect Ctrl-C by trapping...**

```
# Trap ^C 
Signal.trap("INT") { 
   # Do something 
   exit
}
```

**or error handling...**

```
def get_input
   input = ARGF.gets
   input.strip!
   rescue SystemExit, Interrupt => e
   # If we get here, Ctrl-C was encountered
end
```

However, I haven't been able to trap or detect Ctrl-D.

Answer (score 1):

`ARGF` in just a special case of stream. `Ctrl + D` is just end of input.

With this in mind use method `ARGF.eof?`. [Link to documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ARGF.html#method-i-eof-3F)

Comment: I believe that is only valid in the case of a file stream, not the console.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure of your use case but I am assuming you are intending to do something before the script exits. If so then your best bet is probably a bit easier than signal trapping. The `Kernel` `Module` actually offers you an `#at_exit` method that will be executed just prior to the program actually exiting.

Usage: (from [`Kernel#at_exit` Docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Kernel.html#method-i-at_exit))

```
def do_at_exit(str1)
  at_exit { print str1 }
end
at_exit { puts "cruel world" }
do_at_exit("goodbye ")
exit
```

> "produces:"

```
goodbye cruel world
```

as you can see you can define multiple handlers which will be executed in reverse order when the program exits.

Since `Kernel` is included in `Object` you can handle `Object` specifics as well like

```
class People
  at_exit {puts "The #{self.name} have left"}
end
exit
# The People have left
```

or even on instances

```
p = People.new
p.send(:at_exit, &->{puts "We are leaving"})
# We are leaving
# The People have left
```

Additionally for more specific `Object` based implementations you can take a look at [`ObjectSpace.define_finalizer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-define_finalizer).

example of usage:

```
class Person
  def self.finalize(name)
    proc {puts "Goodbye Cruel World -#{name}"}
  end 
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    ObjectSpace.define_finalizer(self, self.class.finalize(@name))
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
p = Person.new("engineersmnky")
exit
# Goodbye Cruel World -engineersmnky
```

This may not be specifically what you want as this will fire when an `Object` is garbage collected as well (not great for ephemeral objects) but if you have objects that should exist throughout the entire application this could still be used similar to an at_exit . Example

```
# requiring WeakRef to allow garbage collection 
# See: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.3/libdoc/weakref/rdoc/WeakRef.html
require 'weakref' # 
p1 = Person.new("Engineer")
p2 = Person.new("Engineer's Monkey")
p2 = WeakRef.new(p2)
GC.start # just for this example
# Goodbye Cruel World -Engineer's Monkey
#=> nil
p2
#=> WeakRef::RefError: Invalid Reference - probably recycled
exit
# Goodbye Cruel World -Engineer
```

As you can see the defined finalizer for `p2` fired because the `Person` was gc'd but the program has not exited yet. `p1`'s finalizer waited until exit to fire because it retained its reference throughout the application.