# Ruby check whether program is currently being closed

Tags: ruby, terminate

How can I check whether current script in Ruby is being closed?
Particularly, in case program is closing, I want to set `@reconnect` to `false`, not to allow web-socket reconnect any more. I tried `Signal.trap("TERM")`, but it doesn't seem to work.

`@reconnect` is an instance variable inside WebsocketClient class, i can't directly change it in my script outside class.

```
class WebsocketClient
    def ws_closed(event)
      $logger.warn "WS CLOSED"
      Signal.trap("TERM") { 
        @stop = true
        @reconnect = false
      }

      unless $reauth
        if @stop
          EM.stop
        elsif @reconnect
          $logger.warn "Reconnecting..."
          EM.add_timer(@reconnect_after){ connect! }
        end
      end
    end
end

at_exit {
  $logger.fatal "Application terminated. Shutting down gracefully..."
  # ...
  # Do some exit work...
  # ...
  exit!
}
```

Output on CTRL-C

```
01-02-2018 12:00:54.59  WARN    > WS CLOSED
01-02-2018 12:00:54.595 WARN    > Reconnecting...
01-02-2018 12:00:54.596 FATAL   > Application terminated. Shutting down gracefully..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Below taken from my answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48025486/trap-ctrl-d-in-a-ruby-script-with-argf/48065329#48065329) but seems more pertinent to your question than the one it is currently attached to:

Your best bet is probably a bit easier than signal trapping. The `Kernel` `Module` actually offers you an `#at_exit` method that will be executed just prior to the program actually exiting.

Usage: (from [`Kernel#at_exit` Docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Kernel.html#method-i-at_exit))

```
def do_at_exit(str1)
  at_exit { print str1 }
end
at_exit { puts "cruel world" }
do_at_exit("goodbye ")
exit
```

"produces:"

```
goodbye cruel world
```

as you can see you can define multiple handlers which will be executed in reverse order when the program exits.

Since `Kernel` is included in `Object` you can handle `Object` specifics as well like

```
class People
  at_exit {puts "The #{self.name} have left"}
end
exit
# The People have left
```

or even on instances

```
p = People.new
p.send(:at_exit, &->{puts "We are leaving"})
# We are leaving
# The People have left
```

Additionally for more specific `Object` based implementations you can take a look at [`ObjectSpace.define_finalizer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-define_finalizer).

example of usage:

```
class Person
  def self.finalize(name)
    proc {puts "Goodbye Cruel World -#{name}"}
  end 
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    ObjectSpace.define_finalizer(self, self.class.finalize(@name))
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
p = Person.new("engineersmnky")
exit
# Goodbye Cruel World -engineersmnky
```

This may not be specifically what you want as this will fire when an `Object` is garbage collected as well (not great for ephemeral objects) but if you have objects that should exist throughout the entire application this could still be used similar to an at_exit . Example

```
# requiring WeakRef to allow garbage collection 
# See: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.3/libdoc/weakref/rdoc/WeakRef.html
require 'weakref' # 
p1 = Person.new("Engineer")
p2 = Person.new("Engineer's Monkey")
p2 = WeakRef.new(p2)
GC.start # just for this example
# Goodbye Cruel World -Engineer's Monkey
#=> nil
p2
#=> WeakRef::RefError: Invalid Reference - probably recycled
exit
# Goodbye Cruel World -Engineer
```

As you can see the defined finalizer for `p2` fired because the `Person` was gc'd but the program has not exited yet. `p1`'s finalizer waited until exit to fire because it retained its reference throughout the application.