# MiniTest: How to test the exit keyword

Tags: ruby, exit, minitest

I have a method 'quit':

```
def quit
  puts "Good bye!"
  exit 
end
```

What I am trying to do is make a mini test assertion that the quit method does indeed quit, none of what I have tried works. Looking for input. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? Maybe you need to look into `Kernel#at_exit` or `ObjectSpace.define_finalizer`? I have posted examples on this SO question: [Ruby check whether program is currently being closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48558953/ruby-check-whether-program-is-currently-being-closed)

Comment: I wonder why would you want to test Ruby standard library.

Answer (score 4):

```
require "minitest/autorun"

def quit_42
  puts "Good bye!"
  exit 42
end

describe :exit_code do
  it "returns 42" do
    err = -> { quit_42 }.must_raise SystemExit
    err.status.must_equal 42
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

*Technically* the following is testing implementation rather than behaviour, but that's probably good enough since the actual behaviour should be covered by ruby's core language tests:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

def quit
  puts "Good bye!"
  exit 
end

describe 'quit' do
  it 'ends the process' do
    assert_raises SystemExit do 
      quit
    end
  end
end
```

Note that this is an unusual scenario; it would typically not be advisable to ever `rescue` from `SystemExit`, since this could cause all sorts of weird behaviour - e.g. this test will actually *pass* if you manually kill the process while it's running (and the process itself wouldn't actually terminate)!

If you were using `rspec`, then the implementation would be similar:

```
RSpec.describe 'quit' do
  it 'ends the process' do
    expect { quit }.to raise_error(SystemExit)
  end
end
```