# Is there a way in ruby to catch when a class has left scope?

Tags: ruby, class, scope, garbage-collection

I want to call a cleanup whenever a class leaves scope.  Something like:

```
def somemethod
    foo = SomeFancyResource.new
    ... some code here ...
end   # foo leaves scope - can we catch that?
```

Is there a method I can add to SomeFancyResource that sees that the variable foo in this case has left scope (presuming we have not returned it or otherwise saved it somehow).  I need this for resource tracking, and don't want to have to make the user do a 'foo.cleanup' at the appropriate time (not to mention the eventual bugs/mistakes this would entail).

I know that the Tempfile class has something *like* this (preusumably using define_finalizer), but evidently it catches garbage collection on the object, and I want to catch that the object has left scope (and garbage collection may happen off in the future)

Comment: [`ObjectSpace.define_finalizer`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-define_finalizer) could work. But I’d probably just make the method yield the instance to a block instead, i.e. `SomeFancyResource.new { |foo| ... }` and clean up from within the method after the block returns.

Comment: define_finalizer doesn't quite work since it doesn't happen until the next instance of GC.  I thought about yield, but I often need to get a disparate collection of these types of resources, and all those yield blocks would get messy.  It also doesn't properly handle the ability to, for example, have a library call that can return functions, so they are still in scope, but eventually call cleanup when the values are actually gone.

Comment: _presuming we have not returned it_ : This is confusing. Do you basically want to know, that which of the objects where `f` had pointed to before during execution, have no references anymore and are allowed to be garbage collected?

Comment: Yes, basically.  Perhaps I should look at it from this perspective - is there a way to see how many references a ruby object has from the perspective of GC?  I suppose I could work it from that angle as well.

Comment: And one of the issues of define_finalizer is that the object is already destroyed - which means I'd need to duplicate the info needed for cleanup in some hash somewhere based on the object id.  So I can see some very hacky and slow solutions that might work with define_finalizer, but they involve regularly calling GC on everything and also duplicating all the info in my resources so I can properly cleanup...  :(

Comment: I’m not really sure what you’re trying to do, but checking if foo is both defined and has the same object ID as it did in some higher-level variable (class variable, instance variable, or global used for debugging purposes) is likely as close as you’re going to get.

Comment: Maybe you can combine `define_finalizer` with [`WeakRef`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.1/libdoc/weakref/rdoc/WeakRef.html). Here is an example I wrote up a while ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48558953/ruby-check-whether-program-is-currently-being-closed

Comment: WeakRef is an interesting possibility, I suppose I could keep a list of all the resource allocations by weakref, then just run GC every time I want to check and see if the resources are gone, and then I know I can allocate them again.