# An unexpected result was encountered when invoking the instance_methods method, resulted in the return of an empty array

Tags: ruby

Please consider the below code

```
class Execute
  def self.inherited(klass)
    puts "Class Inherited: #{klass}"
    klass.run
  end

  def self.run
    puts "Running Instance Methods"
    instance_methods(false).each do |m|
      if m.to_s.start_with?("test_")
        puts "Executing Method: #{m}"
        new.send(m)
      end
    end
  end
end

puts "Before class definition"

class Raja < Execute
  def test_1
    puts 'test_1'
  end

  def test_2
    puts 'test_2'
  end

  def test_3
    puts 'test_3'
  end
end

puts "After class definition"
```

I am currently making an attempt to access the test_1, test_2, and test_3 methods by instantiating an object from the parent class. Upon examination of the program, one may comprehend the actions I am performing. Nonetheless, the issue arises as the invocation of the instance_methods method returns an empty array, contrary to its expected behavior of providing the names of the instance methods, i.e., test_1, test_2, and test_3. I am at a loss as to why this discrepancy is occurring and would greatly appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Class#inherited`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Class.html#method-i-inherited) is called at the moment of inheritance.
At this point no `instance_methods` (non-inherited instance methods since you used `false`)  have been defined.

```
class Raja < Execute #inherited is called here 
 # methods are defined here
end
```

It would be similar to the following

```
class Raja;end 
Raja.instance_methods(false) #=> []
class Raja
  def test_1 = 'test1'
end
```

You could possibly look into [`Module#method_added`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Module.html#method-i-method_added) instead however I am unclear on what the reasoning behind this code is so all I can do is answer the question of *Why* you are experiencing what you you are experiencing.

**Update**
Based on OP comments looking for an auto run mechanism similar to `test-unit`:

As a very simplified [Example](https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/InheritanceTrackerRunner#main.rb):

```
class Tracker
  @@runner = {} 
  def self.runner
    @@runner
  end 
  def self.inherited(klass) 
    runner[klass] = [] 
  end 
  def self.method_added(method_name)
    runner[self] << method_name if method_name.match?(/test_/)
  end 
end 

class Runner 
 def self.run
    Tracker.runner.each do |klass,tests|
      tests.each do |m| 
        klass.new.send(m)
      end 
    end 
  end
end 
# Run the Runner before the program exits
at_exit { Runner.run}
```

Then (foo.rb)

```
require 'runner_tracker'
class Foo < Tracker 
  def test_1
    puts 'test_1'
  end

  def test_2
    puts 'test_2'
  end

  def test_3
    puts 'test_3'
  end
end
```

Output

```
> ruby foo.rb
test_1
test_2
test_3
```

Comment: You are explaining why it is. But my goal is to call the method which start with 'test_' when I run above program. Such a configuration is available when we inherit the Test::Unit::TestCase in our class. So I want to know how they achieved it. Its the gem called test-unit provides this facility.

Comment: @Rajagopalan I explained *why* because that is what you asked. The library you are referencing is far more complex than your example and has absolutely nothing to do with the inherited hook other than to track descendants of the `Test::Unit::TestCase` class and as I mentioned heavily leverages [`method_added`](https://github.com/test-unit/test-unit/blob/master/lib/test/unit/testcase.rb#L144) but even this is not what actually "runs" the code...

Comment: Hey I have seen your edited program, you have actually more or less achieved what I asked for, except onething. In Test::Unit::TestCase, inheriting this `Test::Unit::TestCase` is enough, we don't have to call anything like `Runner.run`. Apart from this, you have achieved everything, great. Thanks.

Comment: @Rajagopalan it uses a simple `at_exit` hook to "auto run". [See Here](https://github.com/test-unit/test-unit/blob/master/lib/test/unit.rb) you can easily implement this (Updated post) although I made a post about exiting hooks a while back too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48565962/1978251

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I want to achieve.